# How to fix slow MySQL Joomla query(s)

Tags: mysql, index

I have a few slow mysql queries and i read that fixing it is easy by just adding indexes to the table. But as of what i am supposed to be indexing in these queries i do not know. (Or how)

First query :

```
# Time: 151209 22:58:49
# Query_time: 6.068411  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 30  Rows_examined: 205825
SET timestamp=1449698329;
SELECT DISTINCT u.id,u.username AS title,u.email AS email,a.thumbnail_ext_id, a.key, a.description, a.alias, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time,a.hits, a.published, a.likes, a.dislikes, a.featured,a.status, a.publish_up, a.publish_down, a.created, a.access,a.language,CASE WHEN a.published > ' ' THEN a.published ELSE 1 END AS published,CASE WHEN a.created_user_id_alias > ' ' THEN a.created_user_id_alias ELSE ua.name END AS author
FROM xlkqf_users AS u
LEFT JOIN `xlkqf_hwdms_users` AS a ON a.id = u.id
LEFT JOIN xlkqf_users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_user_id
LEFT JOIN xlkqf_users AS uam ON uam.id = a.modified_user_id
WHERE a.access IN (1,1,4) AND a.private = 0 AND a.published = 1 AND a.status = 1 AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2015-12-09 21:53:39') AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2015-12-09 21:53:39') AND 1 = 1 OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM xlkqf_hwdms_users WHERE xlkqf_hwdms_users.id = u.id)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 31800, 30;
```

Second query :

```
# Time: 151209 19:41:05
# Query_time: 1.232402  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 22557  Rows_examined: 112815
SET timestamp=1449686465;
SELECT a.id, a.key, a.ext_id, a.title, a.description, a.alias, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time,a.created_user_id, a.thumbnail_ext_id, a.location, a.hits, a.thumbnail, a.type, a.published, a.likes, a.dislikes, a.featured,a.status, a.publish_up, a.publish_down, a.duration, a.source, a.ordering, a.created, a.access,a.language, a.modified, a.created_user_id_alias,CASE WHEN a.created_user_id_alias > ' ' THEN a.created_user_id_alias ELSE ua.username END AS author,CASE WHEN a.ext_id > 0 THEN ext.media_type ELSE a.media_type END AS media_type,ext.ext
FROM xlkqf_hwdms_media AS a
LEFT JOIN xlkqf_users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_user_id
LEFT JOIN xlkqf_users AS uam ON uam.id = a.modified_user_id
LEFT JOIN xlkqf_hwdms_ext AS ext ON ext.id = a.ext_id
WHERE a.access IN (1,1,4) AND (a.private = 0 OR (a.private = 1 && a.created_user_id = 0)) AND a.published = 1 AND a.status = 1 AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2015-12-09 18:36:06') AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2015-12-09 18:36:06') AND a.featured = 0
ORDER BY a.hits DESC;
```

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html) to get the execution plan of those queries, then add the plans to your question, Add relevant `create table` statements too.

Comment: But `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 31800, 30` is just bad.. Makes no sense to skip rows in random ordering, and the random ordering itself is ineffective.

Comment: `= '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR` makes it impossible to use `publish_up` in an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INDEX(private, published, status, access)  -- For Q1
INDEX(featured, access)                    -- For Q2
```

This comes from the basic lesson in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

1. List any columns tested with '='
2. Add one more column  (`access IN`).  (But anything in an `OR` is useless.)

Answer (score 0):

In additional to @RickJames' advice about improving the table structure, I'd also like to mention that you could prune a useless JOIN and entertain the idea of using subqueries instead of LEFT JOINs for conditionally sought values.  You see, for some rows your queries will be theoretically trying to JOIN when you don't ever actually use the associated table data.

`uam` seems safe to omit regardless because its values are never sought.

Both of your queries have a single `WHEN` and `ELSE` in the `CASE` block; when this is the case, I prefer to use `IF()` for clarity.

To boil down what I am saying, remove the `LEFT JOIN xlkqf_users AS ua` and use:

```
IF(a.created_user_id_alias > ' ',
   a.created_user_id_alias,
   (SELECT name FROM xlkqf_users WHERE id = a.created_user_id)
) AS author
```

*vertically stacked for post readability
*truth is, I don't actually know if the above subquery will offer a performance enhancement, it just *feels* right because it uses non-wasteful logic.

Some other notes:

- `a.access IN (1,1,4)` should be `a.access IN (1,4)`
- as @jkavalik stated, there is no need to skip rows in a randomized result set
- `AND 1 = 1` is useless.  If you need to use more parentheses to maintain logic, do so.
- do you actually need to bother checking `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`? I mean the associated condition after `OR` takes care of the logic, right?
- isn't `OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM xlkqf_hwdms_users WHERE xlkqf_hwdms_users.id = u.id)` just asking if `a.id IS NULL`?

To conclude, only you can run the real benchmarks on your actual project data, but my strong recommendation is to clean up your query logic as much as possible ...and don't forget about Mr. James' indexing advice.

p.s. If you don't know how to build these queries using Joomla's query building methods, I am very happy to help at [Joomla Stack Exchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) (but be sure to have a go first).